# Has Thanos ever fought against Malekith The Accursed?

Tags: marvel, thanos

Has Thanos ever fought against Malekith in Marvel Comics? And if so, then who won?

Comment: Short answer, no. Longer answer, noooooooooooooooooooooooo. :)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Ohh okay, really??

Answer (score 8):

It would seem like they never fought, and may not have even met, comics-wise.

It's hard to prove a negative... This won't be my proudest answer, in fact **I'll admit this is more of a meta-answer**, but here is a couple of facts to consider: Thanos first appeared in 1973, Malekith in 1984. This means that if any comic features the two of them, it will have been published after 1984. Now while some early comics are still quite obscure today, by the 80s comics had a broader audience and attention. Now let's Google stuff like:

- `thanos vs malekith`
- `thanos malekith site:marvel.fandom.com` - limits the results to the Wikia, which is heavily documented even if sources have to be checked from times to times, as wikias go)
- `thanos malekith comics -cinematic -"the dark world" -endgame -mcu` - excludes all pages containing the words "MCU", "cinematic", "endgame"... To try and filter out people talking about *Thor: The Dark World* and the consequences on Thanos' plans if the Dark Elves had won

None of these queries brings up a result of Malekith and Thanos meeting, let alone fighting. Now it may just be that no one ever documented it on the Internet, but:

- Pretty much every trivia is documented about Marvel/DC comics. It may take some time to find, but it's there.
- Google's ability to find the stuff you're looking for, even more when you're using search features (such as the site limiter above), is pretty amazing.
- Said ability also takes a lot of your computer's cookies into account to tailor results, and my own computer has *loads* of comic-related cookies.

So I think it's safe to say **as of June 2020, no, Thanos has never fought Malekith**.

---

Now if you swap `malekith` with `dark elves` in the queries above, you'll learn that Thanos *almost* met Dark Elves in the Marvel Cinematic Universe.

> **SlashFilm: So Thanos’s army, we see the Chitauri, we see the Outriders, I think there were some other forces that we hadn’t really seen before. Can you tell me about them, and if they had any names that the Russo brothers or the screenwriters gave to you guys?**
>
> MATT AITKEN [visual effects supervisor for Weta Digital, the company that created the visual effects for *Endgame*‘s final battle]: [...] There’s the Chitauri and their chariots, of course, from the Battle of New York from The Avengers. At one point, there were going to be – potentially dark elves were going to show up, they didn’t make an appearance. [...]
>
> **You mentioned the dark elves. Were there any other big moments like that which you were sad to see get cut?**
>
> The dark elves were mentioned, but we never got as far as rigging them or making them for the battle.
>
> <sub>["‘Avengers: Endgame’: Dark Elves Were Almost in Thanos’s Army; Howard the Duck Was in the Script From the Beginning", Ben Pearson for *SlashFilm*, May 13, 2019](https://www.slashfilm.com/thanoss-army-dark-elves/)</sub>

Comment: https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Mighty_Thor_Vol_1_700 has them in the same issue, I think.

Comment: Ah, but different scenes according to https://marvelheroeslibrary.com/comics/comic-info.aspx?book=The+Mighty+Thor&comic=TMT2017-700 and http://nerdiestkidyouknow.blogspot.com/2017/11/the-mighty-thor-700.html

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I'll check that, but as it's an anniversary issue (#700) I think this is going to be one of these "let's feature every character our protagonist has ever met" chapters

Comment: http://nerdiestkidyouknow.blogspot.com/2018/09/thor-4.html is a bit closer with Thanos attacking the wedding before Sindr uses Malekith to escape.

Comment: https://mightythor.fandom.com/wiki/Thor:_The_Legend_Vol_1_1 is just a series of flashbacks.

Comment: ^_^ Sorry... I was scanning down https://www.comics.org/character/name/Malekith/sort/alpha/?target=sequence&method=icontains&characters=Malekith&logic=True&page=1 to find issues where they both shows up.

Comment: @Jenayah Thanks for the answer and the effort you put in :)